# Is "from" omitted while using the phrasal verb "draw on"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> You get the sense he also saw an opportunity to **draw on** personal experience.

> In this era of change, it makes sense to **draw on** the best expertise available.

When I read these sentences they feel a little off. To me it would make more sense if "draw on from" is used instead of "draw on". Is "from" generally omitted or am I thinking it all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're mixing up two uses of the verb 'to draw': to draw *from*, and to draw *on*. This is not at all surprising, since they have partially overlapping definitions:

- To draw *from*, [is](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/draw)

  > to bring, take, or pull out, as from a receptacle or source:
  > *to draw water from a well*.

  But also:

  > to derive or use, as from a source:
  > *to draw inspiration from Shakespeare*.
- To draw *on*, [is](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/draw--on)

  > to use or exploit (a source, fund, etc.):
  > *to draw on one's experience*.

As you can see, you can draw both *from* or *on* experience, when you're using it to e.g. make a point or write a book.

But when one is drawing *from* "the best expertise available", it suggests that they possess that expertise. In most cases, however, you draw *on* expertise because it is external. Your example sentence talks about an ideal situation: "the best expertise available". That is something the author suggests one would go out of their way for.

Comment: Would "drawing on from experience" be ungrammatical? I wanna add "from" to denote what's the from where something's being drawn upon

Comment: @Satya Draw 'on' also adds the source. In 'drawing on experience' the source is the experience. You can't use both together, no.

Answer (score 4):

In this phrase, "on" is not used in the sense of "on top of something" ("drawing on a table"), but as a replacement of "from", meaning to obtain information from something. Similar to "to feed on (or off) something" (both meaning to obtain food from something).

Comment: I don't think that meaning of "drawing on" was actually being considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idiom as **draw on** or **draw from**. They are identical and interchangeable. They mean to extract inspiration or learning from something and apply it to something else.